# TreeView node icon changes when selected only on custom icons in C#

Tags: c#, treeview, icons

So I have a TreeView in C# and I'm loading icons for folders via P/Invoke. It's working, but on icons which are custom (so to speak), they change to some weird icon, as seen in the image below:

[image: Weird select]

On "Regular" folders, i.e. ones without custom icons, this doesn't happen. Also on things like my HDD icons, it doesn't happen. This is the code I'm using to set the icon key

```
ImageKey = node.FileInfo.UniqueIcon;
SelectedImageKey = ImageKey;
```

As you can see, there's no way `SelectedImageKey` is different from `ImageKey`. However, the icon is still being set as the 0th index of the `ImageList`.I have confirmed via the debugger that the keys are staying the same, after the object is added.

So any ideas why this would be happening only for some icons?

Thanks.

---

## Update

I found a workaround, but I'm not calling it a solution. If I add this to my code:

```
private void FolderTree_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e) {            
   e.Node.SelectedImageKey = e.Node.ImageKey;
}
```

I'm not calling it a solution, because that command only has to run once for it to work. I know that because if I put it on the `AfterExpand` event, then after it does it for one bad one, all the others work after that, even before they're expanded. So it's like something just isn't clicking until after, and resetting just one makes all others work.

Comment: Is this Winforms? Is `node` a `TreeNode`? Where and how is `UniqueIcon` defined?

Comment: Yes. `UniqueIcon` is a combination of `SHFILEINFO`'s `dwAttributes` and `iIcon` properties, joined into a string. The uniqueness is working from what I can tell so far. For the icon in question, it's "0 49".

Comment: Hm. Are those icons actually sitting in an ImageList?

Comment: Yes. `SmallImageList.Images.Add(FileInfo.UniqueIcon, Icon.FromHandle(FileInfo.Icon));`

Comment: Ah, ok. I assume that the whole problem is reproducible? Can you log out the `FileInfo.UniqueIcon` string in a Console.WriteLine? I bet that they are not __unique__. Now this is a strange, lets call it quirk, in ImageList.Add: The keys need __not__ be unique and therefore if you try to access the images by their string key you will only get the ones where the key was inserted first..

Comment: Or you could print out all keys in the ImageList. - Btw: a Treeview in Winforms doesn't have a SmallImageList only a ImageList and a StateImageList. SmallImageList s are used in ListViews

Comment: Sorry, wrong method. The other one is identical except for that one bit. This is straight from the dubugger: http://imgur.com/S4AdARh

Comment: OK, these are identical keys. I guess they are the nodes? But are they unique in the ImageList? Consider: This doesn't throw: `ImageList IL = new ImageList();   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(66, 66);   IL.Images.Add("1"); IL.Images.Add("2");    IL.Images.Add("1", bmp);` so the concept of 'Key' is somewhat weak here, imo.. Maybe for duplicate keys we get a random item of those with that key? It is reproducible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71452/discussion-between-david-and-taw).